# Pipe (a patch in my clipboard) to `git apply`?

Tags: bash, git

I have a patch copied in my OSX clipboard (from ssh). Just wondering if there is a way to write a command to use my clipboard, instead of manually making a patch file

Answer (score 23, accepted):

macOS has the `pbcopy` and `pbpaste` commands for accessing the clipboard:

```
pbpaste | git apply
```

---

Note that while `git apply` accepts patches via stdin, not all commands do. The alternative in those situations would be:

```
pbpaste > /tmp/patch && annoyingprogram /tmp/patch && rm /tmp/patch
```

If you're using the Bash shell, this might also work (or it might not):

```
annoyingprogram <(pbpaste)
```

Answer (score 1):

The focus of the question is MacOS, but for Linux you can also use either:

```shell
xsel --clipboard --input | git apply
```

or

```shell
xclip -selection clipboard -o | git apply
```